# Debugging Ansys ACT C# Extensions

Tags: finite-element-method, ansys, ansys-workbench

I'm using the Ansys ACT Api with C# to create an extension for Ansys (Mechanical).

When developing the extension I need to build a dll file from C# code (using Visual Studio). My problem is that every time I want to test my extension with a new build, I need to restart Ansys Workbench so that the dll of my extension can correctly be replaced.

This is rather time consuming, and I assume there must be a work around, but can't find anything in the documentation or online.

Answer (score 0):

As I discussed about Ansys about this problem, the only solution so far is to copy dll to some location and import this copy instead of the one from you debug/release folder...

Comment: So you mean have another file location, then just change the dll path in the xml or python file which references it?